# wpf Mouseclick on textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, mouseevent

how to set the command and command parameter on mouseclick on textbox in xaml?

Answer (score 3):

Use the PreviewMouseDown of textbox.

Answer (score 1):

TextBoxes don't extend from ButtonBase and therefore don't work with Commands.  What you're trying to do is wrong.  You should ask another question that states your requirements and asks how best to go about achieving them.

Comment: This is how i am doing for textbox enter click. How to do something similar for mouse click as well?

<TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
           x:Name="txtName"/>
<Button Command="{Binding NameCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtName}"
        IsDefault="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=txtName}"/>

Answer (score 1):

As Ortis Mallum answered, the PreviewMouseDown event does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attached command behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).